# Is a bounding box a range or an interval at the final position?

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

For bounding boxes and object detection, the convention is `[ymin, xmin, ymax, xmax]`. My question is, are `ymax` and `xmax` inclusive or exclusive? For python, most ranges are defined to be exclusive at the end. So, is it

```
y = [ymin, ymax)  
x = [xmin, xmax)
```

or

```
y = [ymin, ymax]  
x = [xmin, xmax]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct format

```
y = [ymin, ymax]
x = [xmin, xmax]
```